# How to show decimal point in hive?

Tags: hive, hiveql

I want to display the decimal precision along with the result for decimal datatype in hive. However if there is no fraction part , in hive it will not display the decimal points.

```
hive> select cast(11 as decimal(14,2));
11

hive> select cast(11.22 as decimal(14,2));
11.22
```

In the above example instead of 11 it should display 11.00.How to achieve this?
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

The following `format_number()` function should do it.[Source](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-StringFunctions), return type will be string though.

```
select format_number(11,2)
```

[Note](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-3976): Precision and Scale were added from Hive 0.13.

Answer (score -1):

> Use `round` or `float_number` to set the decimal point where u like , example :

`select round(SUM(150.100 + 127.0090), 2);`

- or

`select float_number(var,2);`